# Merge two list of list objects

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have two School Classes i want two merge those two list into one list.

```
public class School
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<ClassRoom> ClassRooms { get; set; }
}
public class ClassRoom
{
    public int ClassRoomID { get; set; }
    public string GradeName { get; set; }
    public List<Student> Students { get; set; }
    public List<Teacher> Teachers { get; set; }
}
public class Teacher
{
    public int TeacherID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
}
public class Student
{
    public int StudentID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Adress> Adresses { get; set; }
}
public class Adress
{
    public string DetailedAddress { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

This is what i have tried

```
    School school1 = new School();
    School school2 = new School();

    school1.Name = "new NAme";
    school1.ClassRooms.AddRange(school2.ClassRooms);
```

The issue I'm facing is inner list is not adding properly.
The merged list is not having 
List Students
List Teachers

These two are coming as empty.

Comment: _"The merged list is not having List Students List Teachers"_ - You are literally adding the references of `school2.ClassRooms` into `school1.ClassRooms`. You are not copying objects, just copying the reference to the same object. Thus your question is not about merging the lists, instead it's about why `school2`'s ClassRooms don't have any entries for teachers/students. And, unfortunately, you haven't shown us enough code for that one. Perhaps you could provide a [mcve]?

Comment: can you add the example data and your expected result?

Comment: @John
The issue solved, that seemed to be a memory issue;
I restarted the machine and magically it worked

Answer (score -1):

You have to initiate all lists.

```
School school1 = new School();
school1.ClassRooms = new List<ClassRoom>();

school1.ClassRooms.Students = new List<Student>();
school1.ClassRooms.Students.Adresses = new List<Adresses>();

school1.ClassRooms.Teachers = new List<Teachers>();
school1.ClassRooms.Teachers.Adresses = new List<Adresses>();
```

You have to init school 2 as well. Then you can add. Otherwise it will become null. Better use constructor to do this.